# static and non-static function with same name in 2 compilation units

Tags: c

#### 1.c

```
static int test(){
 return 5;
}

int main(){
 return test();
}
```

#### 2.c

```
int test(){
 return 6;
}
```

Above code is compiled fine with `gcc 1.c 2.c` and `5` is returned as expected. My question is, will the linker
choose `test` in `1.c` at all times or its unspecified behaviour and `test` in `2.c` could be chosen as well?

Comment: Local function overrides public one. So `main` will call its local `test`. Linker will most likely realize that nobody is calling `test` from `2.c` and will not even include it in binary.

Comment: Assume test in 2.c is somehow used some other place and it's in binary.

Comment: @snr You can flag them and moderator will remove them. But please, let me know why. Constructive criticism is well appreciated.

Comment: Incidentally, in C, when declaring or defining functions that take no parameters, declare them as `(void)`, not `()`. `()` is an old syntax that means the parameters are not specified, so the compiler will allow a function declared with that to be passed arguments. By using `(void)`, you tell the compiler the function does not accept arguments, and it will warn you if a call accidentally tries to pass an argument.

Comment: @snr: What is your complaint? Saying the local function “overrides” the public one is not a good description of the mechanism by which the function resolution occurs, but it does describe the effect; the local function is indeed used and the external one is not. And some linkers will omit unused routines from the built executable. Apple’s `ld` does if `-dead_strip` is used, although that does not seem to be the default.

Comment: @EricPostpischil sir, firstly, the fact that no source for the idea is there may give rise somebody to use and memorize the idea inaccurately. Secondly, "Linker will most likely realize that ...." doesn't sound technical. At least, it is not the style I'm learning / have learned from you by your answers in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler will ensure that uses of `test` in `1.c` refer only to the `test` defined in `1.c`.

The definition `static int test() {…}` declares `test` with *file scope* (per C 2018 6.2.1 4) and *internal linkage* (per C 2018 6.2.2 3).

*Scope* is where in the source code an identifier is visible. File scope is the largest scope in C—a declaration cannot make an identifier visible outside its translation unit (the source file being compiled with all included headers). The way an identifier declared in one translation unit refers to a function or object defined in another translation unit is through *linkage*.

Since `static int test() {…}` declares `test` with internal linkage, uses of `test` within its scope refer to that definition, the one internal to the translation unit. (There is an exception if another declaration of `test` appears inside a function. An inner declaration can hide an outer declaration and refer to a different entity. There are certain rules about such declarations that I will not cover in this answer.)

In the file `2.c`, the definition `int test() {…}` defines `test` with file scope and *external linkage*. This means that uses of `test` in other translation units can refer to the `test` defined in `2.c`. However, that occurs in another translation unit only when `test` is declared with external linkage in that unit. Since the declaration of `test` in `1.c` has internal linkage, it is not linked to any external definition.